# Clicking "download csv" when using "magic" columns returns JSON

Tags: feature-request, bug, data-explorer, magic-links

When data includes a "magic" column, clicking "Download CSV" causes the magic value to download as JSON instead of a "plain" value.

For example, when running the query:

```
select id [Post Link] from posts where id = 12345678
```

Clicking "Download CSV" downloads:

```
Post Link
"{
  ""title"": ""The title of the question"",
  ""id"": 12345678
}"
```

This value isn't particularly useful for programs that open CSV. Although it seems that it's been deliberately coded to behave like that, IMHO this is not a good choice because it's basically useless.

What I think *should* happen when downloading a magic column is that the "compound" value (an active link that renders as the question title but links using the question id), is *downloaded* as just the plain id value and be labelled as such, ie:

```
PostId,OtherColumns
12345678,"other values"
```

or perhaps even as the two values that comprise the magic value:

```
PostId,Title,OtherColumns
12345678,"Some title","other values"
```

Comment: solution: don't use magic columns when downloading data?

Comment: @JanDvorak Why not just make it work properly? The current behaviour violates the "least astonishment" design principle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a quick fix, I've [changed it to only return the ID](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/pull/41) in the CSV results, pending a pull and redeploy.

For simplicity it will just retain the magic column name for right now, but I'll look into implementing your second suggestion fully a bit later. There are some other possible edge cases that probably need to be addressed as well, so I've put in a TODO item for myself to try and clean up the results conversion code in its entirety – hopefully I can weed them out in the process.